# Footable ajax load php file

Tags: php, ajax, footable

I'm trying to use footable to display data from MySql.

Ajax load work well with .json files : [Footable ajax doc](http://fooplugins.github.io/FooTable/docs/examples/advanced/ajax.html)

But when I tried to load data from php file, it didn't work, loader keep spinning.

My function :

```
    jQuery(function($){
        $('.table').footable({
            "rows": $.get('bdd/horaires/rows.php')
        });
    });
```

And my php file (for testing) :

```
<?php
$returnValue = json_encode('[{"id":1,"firstName":"Annemarie","lastName":"Bruening","something":1381105566987,"jobTitle":"Cloak Room Attendant","started":1367700388909,"dob":122365714987,"status":"Suspended"}]');
echo $returnValue;
```

I tried also json_decode but not working. I tried to simply output string without php line but not working too.

If someone can help me to output data from php, thank !

Comment: Tip 101 for web devs: you should use a web proxy like fiddler to inspect your traffic. then you can look at the raw responses and see what the difference is between the response of your .json files and your php response. this will probably then reveal to you why the php call is not working.

Comment: json_encode works on a PHP object or array, not a string. Your string is already JSON-formatted, so just return it directly.

Comment: Return it directly doesn't work, I've got this answer from chrome console : jquery.js:577 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in [{"id":1,"firstName":"Annemarie","lastName":"Bruening","some‌​thing":1381105566987‌​,"jobTitle":"Cloak Room

Answer (score 1):

json is a string and the string you have is already valid json so you should not manipulate it by encoding it again:

All you need is:

```
<?php
$returnValue = '[{"id":1,"firstName":"Annemarie","lastName":"Bruening","something":1381105566987,"jobTitle":"Cloak Room Attendant","started":1367700388909,"dob":122365714987,"status":"Suspended"}]';
echo $returnValue;
```

Comment: It doesn't work, I've got this answer from chrome console : jquery.js:577 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in [{"id":1,"firstName":"Annemarie","lastName":"Bruening","something":1381105566987,"jobTitle":"Cloak Room

Comment: @Furya If you data does not meet the specifications, you need to fix that. You are returning valid json now, but whether it has the structure that your plugin requires, is something completely different.

Comment: If I put the same string on row.json it work. This line come from footable example.

Answer (score -1):

Ok I find the solution, I change mim type to JSON and it works !

Comment: this is not a answer, please make sure as solution or else add comment

Comment: Putting header('Content-Type: application/json'); in my php file worded for me